# How to install laravel/breeze without npm?

Tags: laravel, npm, installation, breeze

Is it possible to install breeze on laravel 8 without npm?
The [official documentation](https://github.com/laravel/breeze) does not mention it, but after you run the final

```
php artisan breeze:install
```

you will get a message to run **npm install**. My hosting provider does not offer npm.

Thanks

Comment: @ThânLƯƠNG Why do you ask? The question is how to install breeze without npm.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.